# TensorFlow JS Input Shape Example

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow.js

## heading

i am new to artificial intelligence and trying to learn with tensorflow js. any help/guidance is appreciated.

i have followed the guide here and it seems to work as expected:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-regression/index.html#0

in the example provided, it uses the dataset from: https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-tutorials/carsData.json

in the example the props used are: `Miles_per_Gallon` and `Horsepower`.

## question

i would like to know how to adjust the code so that in the input shape, i am able to pass in all the properties available in the sample data for it to create (ideally) a more accurate prediction.

i have looked into the documentation and think this is the page related to my question: https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/models_and_layers

... but i do not understand enough how to interpret the sample data into an input shape for tensorflow.

Comment: Could you please add relevant code to the question ? It will be easier to help

Comment: sure. updated with code example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat, and this is what I figured so far (since no other answers).

There are 2 places where you define the shape. 1. When you create the tensor 2. When you create the model.

1. When you create the tensor

```js
const x1 = [18, 8, 307, ...] // aka Miles per gallon, cylinders, displacement, ...
const xs = [x1, x2, x3,...]
// Then you create the tensor, I try to have it dynamic like so:
const tensorXs = tf.tensor2d(xs, [xs.length, xs[0].length])
```

So you can change the number of data points dynamically and add more features and it gets it right.

2. When you create the model

```
const layerOneInputShape = [xs[0].length]
const layerOneUnits = xs[0].length

model.add(tf.layers.dense({ inputShape: layerOneInputShape, units: layerOneUnits, useBias: true }))
```

And this worked for me.